# ASP.NET web application deployment with web Deploy 3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, microsoft-web-deploy

I have a asp.net web application which has to deployed on IIS on another PC without the involvement of Visual Studio. Do I need to package it as I cannot publish it to another PC. I have installed web deploy 3.5 on the other PC and created a Web-deploy package of the application. how do I proceed with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you can find answer

[IIS remote web deploy Link](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)

My personal summery ...
Goto IIS->Default Web Site->IIS Manager Permission 
and Give Administrator the access to IIS

1.Install **httpPlatformHandler**

2.Install **WebDeploy 3.5**

3.Publish Web Tab in **connection** menu

i.Publish Mehtod: WebDeploy

ii.Server:https://192.168.xx.xx:8172/msdeploy.axd

iii.Site Name: `Default Web Site/nameOfWebSite`

iv.UserName:Set userName by Above link.For **localhost** not required

v.Password:Set userName by Above link.For **localhost** not required

vi.Destination URL:http://192.168.xx.xx/nameOfWebSite

and click publish..

Edit:
Some additional link might be helpful.
[link2](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-remote-agent)
[link3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx)